# store_accessor not saving in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have the following table in the database

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | name        | data       |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 1  | string      | hstore     |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

with the following model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :data, :author, :pages
end
```

However, the write methods generated from store_accessor aren't saving to the database when I run the following:

```
> Book.create name: "Catch-22", author: "Joseph Heller"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id | name        | data                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | Catch-22    | {"author": "Joseph Heller"} |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
> book = Book.find(1)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id | name        | data                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | Catch-22    | {"author": "Joseph Heller"} |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
> book.pages = "453"
"453"
> book.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
true
> book
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id | name        | data                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | Catch-22    | {"author": "Joseph Heller"} |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
> book.pages
nil
```

It's my understanding that the setter methods generated by `store_accessor` should merge the key value pair into the original hash, yet they don't seem to be.  How can I get them to merge in the new data?

Comment: What is `store_accessor`? Is it some kind of `attr_accessor`?

Comment: @Pavan http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html it is similar to attr_accessor for hstore variables

Comment: @Pavan no worries, although the examples on the page don't seem to be the norm.  http://mikecoutermarsh.com/using-hstore-with-rails-4/ seems to be the defacto was of calling it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if it is mistake or feature in rails hstore implementation. ActiveRecord does not recognise that hstore attribute was changed and does not save it. So you have to enforce it.

```
book = Book.find(1)
book.pages = "453"
book.data_will_change!
book.save
```

`book.data_will_change!` enforces data attribute to save.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/901a0c8b4a3b1de8ff1ec8feb4b67f727c07dc8b/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L135 it seems like rails sends that method automatically.  Explicitly calling it still did not cause it to update in the database

Comment: Oh my mistake - calling it did work!  I just wasn't saving it in a variable in my example, so when I copy pasted nothing happened.  That is weird that you have to explicitly call it though!

Comment: Same issue and same solution for JSONB columns... Very weird